Showing Fatal Error in my Wordpress Website
I am facing the following error since today morning:
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function current_user_can() in
/home/craftsowl/public_html/wp-includes/kses.php

How do I fix this error?

Does this answer your question? Wordpress - current_user_can in functions.php

The implication is that the site was previously working, so the first question to answer is "What changed?" - i.e. what events lead to the error occurring? Was WordPress or any plugins updated; were any core files or theme files edited; did you switch or update the theme; were any changes made on the site, the host-server or database ... etc.
